# AWS S3 - User Policy Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a user with the following policy, and I'm using DragonDisk client program. This user can do everything under bucket1/folder1/, except accessing a file's properties (access denied). I can't figure out why. Any idea? Thanks.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
    },
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket1"],
      "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":[""],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket1"],
      "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["folder1/*"]}}
    },
    {
       "Action":["s3:*"],
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/folder1/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the access denied is actually coming from AWS, you might want to use CloudTrail to see what DragonDisk is doing when you access a file's properties. Or see if DragonDisk offers any internal logging or debug info of its API calls to AWS.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.